# Return type from a Comparator

Tags: java

**What does the return value inside the Comparator actually mean?**

For example :

```
class TreeSetDemo
{
    public static void main(String arg[])
    {
        TreeSet t=new TreeSet(new MyComparator());
        t.add(new Integer(20));
        t.add(new Integer(10));
        t.add(new Integer(30));
        t.add(new Integer(100));
        System.out.println(t); 
    }    

    class MyComparator implements Comparator 
    {    
        public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) 
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

**If the return type is 1 then its actually returning**

[20, 10, 30, 100]

**If the return type is -1 then its actually returning**

[100, 30, 10, 20]

**If the return type is 0 then its actually returning**

[20]

Please tell me what does this indicate?

Comment: usually `0` indicates `==` , `1` indicates `>` and `-1` indicates `<`

Comment: "1", "-1" and "0" are not types, but values.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

The return `value` (not `type`, the type is `int`) tells the caller (the thing sorting the data):

```
-1 : o1 < o2
0 : o1 == o2
+1 : o1 > o2
```

If you always return the same value (o, 1, -1) for the comparator, regardless of it's inputs, then you're not using it correctly. You need to base the value returned on the values passed in. The idea is that the data structure (or sorter) calls the comparison function any time it needs to order two elements, to find out what order to put them in.

Its worth noting that the positive/negative integer values (-1, +1) don't need to be 1, they can be any positive/negative numbers. It's just common practice to return -1/+1.

Comment: How to achieve ascending or descending order? It is worth to imagine that checked two elements' positions are swapped if comparator returns a value bigger than 0. Another thinking, the sort function always sorts ascending. By returning -1 while o1>o2, you say to sort function that do not swap the elements. You achieve descending sorting by this way.

Answer (score 3):

You are confusing **return-type** and **return-value**. The return-type is `int`. The return value is described in the [documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html):

> Returns a negative integer, zero, or a
>   positive integer as the first argument
>   is less than, equal to, or greater
>   than the second.

Answer (score 2):

the way comparator is leveraged here is wrong but for clarifying your doubt why only [20] id being written when return value is 0...

You are using a `TreeSet` which doesn't hold identical values(Property of Set). So when the values are compared and return value is *zero*, Java treats them as equal and retain only the first value. Hence, you are seeing only one value in return.

Answer (score 1):

[Comparator documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#compare%28T,%20T%29) -- Returns:
a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as the first argument is less than, equal to, or greater than the second.

Answer (score 0):

It's about sort algorithm which needs compare.

Correct:

```
class MyComparator implements Comparator<Integer> {
    public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2) {
        // Calling the Integer class's compareTo method
        return o1.compareTo(o2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you want to sort based on this comparator you need to place some logic in the comparator.  Your comparator only returns 0 which means equal

```
class MyComparator implements Comparator {

    public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return o1.compareTo(o2);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think this will compile, because `Object` is not comparable.

Comment: `o1` (Object) class doen't have `compareTo` method, though you can cast and use it as `return ((String)o1).compareTo((String)o2);`

Answer (score 0):

```
PriorityQueue<Integer> pq = new PriorityQueue<>(new Comparator<Integer>(){
           @Override
           public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2) {
               if(o1.intValue() > o2.intValue()){
                   return -1;
               }else if(o1.intValue() < o2.intValue()){
                   return 1;
               }
               return 0;
           }
       });
       pq.add(44);
       pq.add(3);
       pq.add(2);pq.add(5); 
System.out.println(pq.poll());
//outpu 44
```

it will sort the element when adding to elements to it in descending order. it will compare two objects based on the return value it will maintain the order.