# Sorting in Descending order using Comparator

Tags: java, sorting

I'm trying to sort the list in descending order using Comparator Interface. But the values are not sorted in descending order. Not sure what i'm doing wrong here.

```
public class Student {

    int rollNo;
    String name;
    int age;
    
    public Student(int RollNo, String Name, int Age){
        this.rollNo = RollNo;
        this.name = Name;
        this.age = Age;
    }
}

public class AgeComparator implements Comparator<Student>{

    @Override
    public int compare(Student o1, Student o2) {
        return o1.age > o2.age ? 1 :(o1.age < o2.age ? -1 : 0); //Ascending
         
        //return o1.age < o2.age ? -1 :(o1.age > o2.age ? 1 : 0); // Descending
    }

}

public class Comparator_Sort {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
        ArrayList<Student> al = new ArrayList<Student>();
        al.add(new Student(5978, "Vishnu", 50));
        al.add(new Student(5979, "Vasanth", 30));
        al.add(new Student(5980, "Santhosh", 40));
        al.add(new Student(5981, "Santhosh", 20));
        al.add(new Student(5982, "Santhosh", 10));
        al.add(new Student(5983, "Santhosh", 5));
        
        
        Collections.sort(al, new AgeComparator());
        
        for(Student s : al){
            System.out.println(s.rollNo+" "+s.name+" "+s.age);
        }
    }
}
```

I can be able to sort the list in ascending order, whereas i'm unable to do it for descending order

```
return o1.age > o2.age ? 1 :(o1.age < o2.age ? -1 : 0); //Sorted in Ascending
return o1.age < o2.age ? -1 :(o1.age > o2.age ? 1 : 0); // Not sorted in Descending
```

Comparator documentation -- Returns: a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as the first argument is less than, equal to, or greater than the second. The source is found from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6478515/return-type-from-a-comparator)

Can anyone tell me why the sorting for descending is not working?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your two ternary conditional operators produce the same result (since you swapped both `>` with `<` and `-1` with `1`):

```
return o1.age > o2.age ? 1 :(o1.age < o2.age ? -1 : 0); //Sorted in Ascending
return o1.age < o2.age ? -1 :(o1.age > o2.age ? 1 : 0); // Not sorted in Descending
```

For descending order you need :

```
return o1.age > o2.age ? -1 :(o1.age < o2.age ? 1 : 0);
```

Comment: If u check the source i have provided, it follows the below criteria

Comment: I'm following the same approach, but descending order sorting is not working

Comment: @Aishu `-1 : o1 < o2 0 : o1 == o2 +1 : o1 > o2` produces ascending order. If you want descending order, you need to reverse the roles of `o1` and `o2`.

Comment: Got little confused from the source http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6478515/return-type-from-a-comparator

Comment: @Aishu As I said, that question (or rather the accepted answer) describe the logic for getting ascending order. `compare` should return a negative value if o1 should come before o2. For ascending order that also means that o1<o2. For descending order, the opposite is true - you return a negative value if o1>o2.

Answer (score 10):

@Eran already pointed out the error in your comparator.

I'd like to add that you may just return `o1.age - o2.age`. The result of comparison does not have to be exactly `-1` or `1` for `<` or `>` it may be just negative or positive.

And you could have also called [`Comparator.reversed`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#reversed--). Or `Comparator.comparing(Student::getAge).reversed()`.

Answer (score 2):

The age value is an integer, and it seems that it is always positive, you can use this shorten code.

```
return o1.age - o2.age; // Ascending
return o2.age - o1.age; // Descending
```

This code cannot be used for negative values.

For example,

if `o1.age = 10`, `o2.age = 11`, this code will return `-1` for ascending and `1` for descending, that is correct.

But the case `o1.age = -10`, `o2.age = -11`, this code will return `1` for ascending and `-1` for descending, that is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

Abusing ternary conditions is error-prone because not readable.

Why not simply write classic `if-else-if` for the descending comparator ?

```
public class AgeComparatorDesc implements Comparator<Student> {

  @Override
  public int compare(Student o1, Student o2) {
    if (o1.age > o2.age) {
        return -1;
    } else if (o1.age < o2.age) {
        return 1;
    }    
     return 0;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can directly use a comparator class instance. Below is the code example.

Assuming the you define a getter method `"getAge()"` for student.

```
Comparator<Student> m_studentComparator = new Comparator<Sudent>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Student lhs, Student rhs) {
            return rhs.getAge().compareTo(lhs.getAge());  // Descending order
        }
    };

Collections.sort(<<Your list>> , m_studentComparator);   // this would return the descending order list.
```

If you want an Ascending order list, just change the return statement in the overridden method to

```
return lhs.getAge().compareTo(rjs.getAge());    // Ascending order.
```

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: age needs to be of class Integer and not to be defined as the primitive type int

Comment: @Davide One could do that. That helps in handling null cases for age. Thanks !

Comment: Sure, I just wanted to emphasize this aspect

Answer (score 0):

Well you should either write it as:

```
return o1.age < o2.age ? 1 :(o1.age > o2.age ? -1 : 0);
```

or write it as:

```
return o1.age > o2.age ? -1 :(o1.age < o2.age ? 1 : 0);
```

Your current attempt will still sort it in ascending order.

Answer (score 0):

```
return o1.age > o2.age ? -1 :(o1.age < o2.age ? 1 : 0);
```

though for descending simply just multiply your ascending return statement with -1. like this

```
-1*(return o1.age > o2.age ? 1 :(o1.age < o2.age ? -1 : 0))
```