# How to sort list of objects?

Tags: java, sorting

I have a list of objects, each object has a method that returns distance from player to said object like that

```
object.distance(player)
```

now i need to sort that list from loqwest distance to furthest

Comment: What have you tried? What specifically do you need help with?

Comment: What is your take on this. How would you solve it?

Comment: I tried iterating through the list  and storing to an array distance for each object with key then sorting and returning the first, but is there better way of doing this?

Comment: I think a bit more code would be helpful here. In essence, [you sort using a comparator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41141672/java-sorting-in-descending-order-using-comparator), but if there is a `List` of some object, I'm not sure where the `player` is coming from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use interface `java.lang.Comparable` in java

Example (pseudo code) assuming object.distance(player) returns an Integer value

```
class Distance implements Comparable<Distance>{
  /**
    * Compare a given Distance with this object.
    */
    public int compareTo(Distance o) {
        return this.distance(player).compareTo(o.distance(o.player));
    }
}
```

now you can sort your list like

```
Collections.sort(YourListOfDistance)
```

here some reference

[When should a class be Comparable and/or Comparator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1440134/when-should-a-class-be-comparable-and-or-comparator)