# Internals of Collections.sort in java

Tags: java, sorting

I am trying to understand when does elements in a list swap during sorting process . So far my understanding is during comparison when we return -1 or 0 no swapping happens and when we return 1 swapping happens. Here is the code

```
public class ArraySort {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer [] input = {1,10};
        List<Integer> inputList =Arrays.asList(input);
        Collections.sort(inputList,(a,b)->a>b?-1:1);
        System.out.println(inputList);
    }
}
```

Returns [10,1] ---- I understand this. Since we are returning 1 from comparison swapping happens.

```
public class ArraySort {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer [] input = {1,10};
        List<Integer> inputList =Arrays.asList(input);
        Collections.sort(inputList,(a,b)->a>b?1:-1);//changed the signs
        System.out.println(inputList);
    }
}
```

Returns [1,10] -- I understand this as no swapping happens since returning -1.

```
public class ArraySort {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer [] input = {1,10};
        List<Integer> inputList =Arrays.asList(input);
        Collections.sort(inputList,(a,b)->a>b?-1:-1); // both are negative.
        System.out.println(inputList);
    }
}
```

Returns [10,1] -- I DON'T understand this as why swapping happens since returning -1 should not cause swapping right? Please clarify my misunderstanding.

Again i tried posts on this forum but could get a satisfactory answer on my question. 
[Return type from a Comparator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6478515/return-type-from-a-comparator)

Comment: Your comparator is inconsistent : `compare(a,b)` and `compare(b,a)` both return `-1`. Whatever the internals are, the result will be inconsistent too.

Comment: This is real crazy... Plz read carefully what comparator does. In essentials it's just how you compare two given values. When you set -1:-1 you just broke it, now it always returns 'less than'.

Comment: To answer this, one should know exactly which algorithm is used. A look at these posts should be useful to potential answerers :  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12228659/what-is-the-sorting-algorithm-for-java ,

Comment: Also, if you have elements which are both "less than the other", you should not be able to rely on whatever you imagine the result would be. So the fact that you get weird results is **not** surprising.

Comment: moreover, to cite a comment on my linked question, : "It's also worth noting that while the Oracle/Sun implementation referenced uses those algorithms, they're not required by the specification, and may differ in other implementations - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html – Marc Bollinger Sep 1 '12 at 14:45

Answer (score 3):

From the [javadoc of Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html):

> In the foregoing description, the notation `sgn(expression)` designates the mathematical signum function, which is defined to return one of `-1`, `0`, or `1` according to whether the value of expression is negative, zero or positive.
>
> The implementor must ensure that `sgn(compare(x, y)) == -sgn(compare(y, x))` for all `x` and `y`. (This implies that `compare(x, y)` must throw an exception if and only if `compare(y, x)` throws an exception.)
>
> The implementor must also ensure that the relation is transitive: `((compare(x, y)>0) && (compare(y, z)>0))` implies `compare(x, z)>0`.
>
> Finally, the implementor must ensure that `compare(x, y)==0` implies that `sgn(compare(x, z))==sgn(compare(y, z))` for all `z`.

Your implementation breaks these assumptions: As you always return `-1`, you break at least the first assumptions:

`sgn(compare(x, y)) == -sgn(compare(y, x))` does not hold if you always return `-1`: `sgn(compare(x, y)) == sgn(compare(y, x))` for all `x` and `y`.

This leads to undefined behavior since the sort code relies on you correctly adhering to this contract.

Answer (score 0):

You did not break it. What you did is that you are telling the `Comparator` no matter what you compare it is always lower to the comparable value. For example if you use it like this

```
 Integer[] input = {
     1, 6, 8, 2, 10
 };
 List < Integer > inputList = Arrays.asList(input);
 Collections.sort(inputList, (a, b) - > a > b ? -1 : -1); // both are negative.
 System.out.println(inputList);
```

It will print `[10, 2, 8, 6, 1]`. It reverts the list since it starts by comparing from left-to-right.

Answer (score 0):

This `Comparator` implementation doesn't respect the specification of `Comparator.compare()` :

```
Collections.sort(inputList,(a,b)->a>b?-1:-1); // both are negative.
```

The specification states that :

> the implementor must ensure that (compare(x, y)) == -sgn(compare(y, x)) for  > all x and y.

In your implementation, you don't have this equality but this one :

```
sgn(compare(x, y)) == sgn(compare(y,> x))
```

Not respecting the contract of the method can give unpredictable results as the Collection methods manipulate your object.